# My android layout changes each time i chose a different device in emulator even if they have approximately same size?

Tags: android, layout, screen

Here is my xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ResultText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="#EEEEEE" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/InputText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ResultText"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ResultText"
        android:background="#BBBBBB"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:text="5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button6"
        android:text="7" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button7"
        android:text="8" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button5"
        android:text="9" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonMultiply"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/buttonDivide"
        android:text="x" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSubtract"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/buttonAdd"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/buttonAdd"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="-" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonDivide"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/buttonAdd"
        android:text="/" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonAdd"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/buttonSubtract"
        android:text="+" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/buttonDivide"
        android:text="4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button8"
        android:text="3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonDot"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button0"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button0"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button7"
        android:text="." />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button3"
        android:text="2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button0"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button7"
        android:text="6" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button0"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button6"
        android:text="0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/InputText"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"
        android:text="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonEqual"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/buttonDot"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/buttonDot"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/buttonMultiply"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button8"
        android:text="=" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonDel"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/buttonDot"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/buttonDot"
        android:text="del" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSin"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button9"
        android:text="sin" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonCos"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button0"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/buttonSin"
        android:text="cos" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonTan"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/buttonDot"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/buttonCos"
        android:text="tan" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonCot"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/buttonSec"
        android:text="cot" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSec"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/buttonCosec"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/buttonCosec"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/buttonCot"
        android:text="sec" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonCosec"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/buttonTan"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/buttonTan"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/buttonSec"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:text="csec" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonPow"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/buttonSin"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttonSin"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/buttonSin"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:text="yX" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonLog10"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/buttonPow"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/buttonPow"
        android:text="log" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonLoge"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/buttonLog10"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/buttonLog10"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/buttonLog10"
        android:text="ln" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSquare"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/buttonLoge"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/buttonLoge"
        android:text="sqr" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSqrt"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/buttonSquare"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/buttonSquare"
        android:text="sqrt" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonFactorial"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/buttonSqrt"
        android:text="x!" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSinh"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/buttonPow"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttonPow"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/buttonLoge"
        android:text="sinh" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonCosh"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/buttonSinh"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/buttonSinh"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/buttonLoge"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/buttonSqrt"
        android:text="cosh" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonTanh"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/buttonSqrt"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/buttonFactorial"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/buttonCosh"
        android:text="tanh" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

here are some screen shots:

[image]

As you can see the left portion is not filled completely it is on a 4.65 inch xhdpi screen
On a 4 inch hdpi screen its perfect covering full width and full height

Comment: where is your screen shot?

Comment: I wonder if a TableLayout would be a more fitting type of ViewGroup for your layout? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html

Comment: I could not add it first because it asks for reputation of 10.Now rajesh has added it the problem is that left part of my screen is blank. It however fits perfectly on a 4 inch hdpi emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, what Ben Pearson suggested, you can use TableLayout and several TableRow layouts. For example, a single row layout XML might look like this:

```
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="6" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="7" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="8" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonDivide"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="/" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonMultiply"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="x" />
</TableRow>
```

Note that since TableRow is a subclass of LinearLayout, it understands the layout_weight attribute on its children. Set the layout_width to 0dp and layout_weight to 1 on each button (or 2, for some buttons).

Comment: Thank you bolot it works really well. Thank you very much. :)